# Linq mapping style DB access, for ADO

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

The Linq framework has "mapping" functionality where you attach `[Column]` and `[Table]` to properties and classes, and then the DB schema is inferred from those classes.

Is there any way to achieve similar behaviour in ADO, where data are mapped to actual objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Maybe? I've been looking through the documentation, but it's large and confusing. Entity examples such as this one (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738468.aspx) still show type-unsafe property name string access to object data, instead of generic-based access to actual objects.

Comment: It seems that I specifically want the Object Services section of the Entity framework, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386871.aspx

Comment: Alright, so http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738470.aspx gives me three options - EntityObject, POCO, and POCO Proxy. Which of these will I be able to use in a simple manner without having to attach some other random crap (CSDL, etc.)?

Comment: Using POCO with Code First is what I recommend for the simplest objects.